# Playing 2 sounds with AVAudioPlayer without sleep();

Tags: avaudioplayer, playback, audio

I have this 2 sounds playing in a `scrollview` using `AVAudioPlayer`.

The problem is that the `sleep()` is creating lags and I need an alternative to playing two sounds one after the other more easily without the sleep function.

PS: the name of the file is given by the page in the scrollView in which the user is.

```
   if( nextPage!=6 )  {
    [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, nextPage*250, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    pgCtr.currentPage=nextPage;


    NSString *path;
    NSError *error;
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pas%02i",nextPage+1] ofType:@"m4a"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
        player.volume = 0.5f;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [player play];
    }
    sleep(1);

    NSString *path2;
    NSError *error2;
    path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"passun%02i",nextPage+1] ofType:@"m4a"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path2])
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2] error:&error2];
        player.volume = 0.5f;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [player play];
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Also, the solution: set up the delegate of the `AVAudioPlayer` object. Start the second player only when the first has finished playing.